# .htaccess return 404 when not image file on subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a .htaccess file that should force only image files to be served if the subdomain is `img0.example.info`, `img1.example.info`, `img2.example.info` et cetera. I want to deliver the descriptive markup in 404.html with a 404 response code but it's just showing 500 Internal Server Error error.

Here is the contents of my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine on

    # If request is via an image subdomain, throw error 404 for any file types other than images
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^img[0-9]+\.example\.info$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [R=404,L]

    ErrorDocument 404 /404.html 

</IfModule>
```

It partially works in that .jpg, .jpeg, .gif and .png files all get served properly but I cannot get that neat 404 message. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `/404.html` is also getting caught by this rule.

Try this code:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html 

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine on

    # If request is via an image subdomain, throw error 404 for any file types other than images
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^img[0-9]+\.example\.info$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule !^404\.html$ - [R=404,L,NC]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much. So to clarify: I had 2 problems. 1) Error Document should have been defined outside the IfModule and 2) The rewrite rule had to make sure it wasn't causing an infinite loop. Have I got that right?

Answer (score 0):

Another option of just redirecting to the 404 file as well.

```
# If request is via an image subdomain, throw error 404 for any file types other than images

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^img[0-9]+\.example\.info$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.+)\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/404.html$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /404.html [R=404,L]
```